# How to load Gutenberg block styles when rendering blocks in another page

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

I want to load the Gutenberg block content of one post into a custom template.

I have tried two ways.

Firstly by rendering the post content:

```
$args = array(
       'post_type' => 'page',
       'id' => $post_id
   );

   $your_query = new WP_Query( $args );
   while ( $your_query->have_posts() ) : $your_query->the_post();
       the_content();
   endwhile;
```

I also tried rendering each block individually

```
$post = get_post($post_id); 
$blocks = parse_blocks($post->post_content);
    
foreach ($blocks as $block) {
    echo render_block($block);
}
```

In both cases it rendered the Gutenberg content, but not the related styles.

In the original page, there are both the gutenberg blocks and gutenberg inline style.
Is there a way to render the blocks and the blocks styles in aother page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [do_blocks()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/do_blocks/) so the blocks render method within the post content is called and the front-end styles are enqueued as needed in your custom post template, eg:

```
$post = get_post($post_id); 
echo do_blocks($post->post_content);
```

To confirm if the style sheet is queued for loading, use:

```
global $wp_styles;

if ( $wp_styles->queue ){
    // Print out a list of all the currently enqueued styles
    echo '<pre>', print_r( $wp_styles->queue ), '</pre>';
}
```